Cosine transform involving both types of modified bessel functions
For $z>0$, $\nu>-1/2$, $r>\hat{r}>0$, it is known that
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\infty} I_{\nu}(\beta\hat{r})K_{\nu}(\beta r)\cos(\beta z)\,d\beta=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{r\hat{r}}}Q_{\nu-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{r^2+\hat{r}^2+z^2}{2r\hat{r}}\right).
\end{equation*}
For $z>0$, $\nu>-1/2$, $r>\hat{r}>1$, I want to evaluate
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{I_{\nu}(\beta)K_{\nu}(\beta r)K_{\nu}(\beta\hat{r})\cos(\beta z)}{K_{\nu}(\beta)}\,d\beta.
\end{equation*}
Mathematica is able to evaluate the special case $\nu=1/2$, but that does not help me in finding or guessing the result for the general case.
